# Is there a way to integrate RingCentral data with on promises database?

Tags: database, api, rest, ringcentral, ringcentral-webhooks

Is there any way to fetch and load RingCentral data in our database? Can we use REST API or it can be integrated directly?

I'm trying to retrieve reporting data.

How exactly can I get access token, is it generated by RingCentral?

Answer (score 0):

What reporting data are you trying to sync?

### General REST API Info

The RingCentral REST API can be used to retrieve and load data into your own database or any other system. There is also an event system that supports webhooks and client-based PubNub subscriptions.

Learn more about the REST API here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference

In addition to using the REST API directly, a variety of SDKs are available here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/sdks

### Reporting Data API

Can you be more specific on what kind of reporting data you are interested in?

It is popular to sync the Call Log CDR (Call Details Record) data to databases. Read more on the Call Log APIs here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/voice/call-log/reading-call-log

### Getting an Access Token for the API

Regarding authentication to get an access token to use the API, RingCentral supports OAuth 2.0. See the following Developer Guide page on Authentication which covers the various OAuth 2.0 grant type approaches that are supported, including

- Authorization Code Flow (3-legged flow)
- Password Flow
- Implicit Grant Flow

PKCE is also supported with the Authorization Code Flow.

https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/authentication

### Direct Integration

Direct integration is available via various pre-integrated connectors.

See the RingCentral App Gallery to see various apps that have been integrated like Salesforce, HubSpot and others.

https://www.ringcentral.com/apps/

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve reporting data. How exactly can I get access token, is it generated by ringcentral?

Comment: I added your additional info to you question for more general clarification of your ask, and extended my answer to respond as well. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: If I use following real-time application for extracting json data, how can I get "Baseuri" and "accessTiken"?: 
 https://developer.niceincontact.com/API/RealTimeDataAPI#/RealTime/get-agents-client-data